# Entire Page getting reloaded whenever calling a Component of different module from app.module using RouterModule.forChild()

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular5, angular-routing

I have a navigation bar menu from where i am calling a component of different module, Component is getting called but page is getting reloaded. Please help.

I have defined loadChildren in RouterModule.ForRoots inside the App.Module and  RouterModule.forChild(routes) inside the child module, but there is reloading problem occurring.

```
app.module.ts

RouterModule.forRoot([
{ path: '', loadChildren: () => AdminModule, pathMatch: 'full' } 
])
```

```
app.component.html

<div class='row'>
  <app-layout>
    <div class="admin">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </app-layout>
</div>

<app-layout></app-layout> is my shared header and footer.
```

```
admin.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: UserManagementComponent
  }
];

In imports - 

RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

Do not want page reload when calling the '/user' component from Menu.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are loading the module looks a little weird to me, maybe you can try it this way:

```
{ path: '', loadChildren: './AdminModule.module#AdminModule' },
```

In the load children property you should put the physical path first and after the hashtag you put the class name.

I don't see problems with your feature module router although I prefer to put it on a separate file to make it cleaner.

Comment: I did this, but still facing the same reload issue. :(

Comment: mjjjmmm are you loading the appModule in the feature module? if you are, you shouldn't.